# what is getAgreedToTerms()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I ran [getAgreedToTerms()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_domainuser#getAgreedToTerms) on all users of my domain and results are not clear.

1. For new created users that have never made first connection, I have sometimes FALSE and sometimes TRUE.
2. For daily connecting users, some are TRUE, some FALSE.
   My domain has no additional services activated, so users nevers signed TOS at first connection.

What is really this property ?

Comment: Does your domain currently require users to agree to the Terms of Service when they first login?

Comment: Hi there, Could we see the code your trying to run to see if we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of info on the TOS, if your domain is set to "Rapid Release" and/or new services to "Automatic", even if you only have core services, the domain can ask for agreement.

It is due to the fact that on automatic new google services, if a service is added by google it will be activated by default.